# Adding layout to main layout

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.inigui()
    def inigui(self):
        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)
        self.scroll_area_print()
        self.showMaximized()
    def scroll_area_print(self):
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        widget = QWidget()        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()  
        button = QPushButton("Test1337")        
        layout.addWidget(button)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        scroll_area.setWidget(widget)
        self.layout_main.addLayout(layout)
```

This code does not work for me.

It shows me blank window.

What do I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `self.layout_main.addLayout(layout)` to `self.layout_main.addWidget(scroll_area)`